# Why does for-each work, but for...of... doesn't?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

This is my code to fetch data from firebase:

```js
const querySnapshot = await db.collection('entries').get()
```

I want to add the data of every entry-element to a new array for which I got two ways to do it:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((entry) => {
   const entryData = entry.data()
   entries.value.push(entryData)
})
```

and

```
for (const entry of querySnapshot) {
      const entryData = entry.data()
      if (entry) { entries.value.push(entryData)
}
```

The first solution works, but the second throws this error: `TypeError: "querySnapshot is not iterable"`. Aren't the two ways basically doing the same? Why does on throw an error while the other doesn't?

Comment: Because whatever `get()` is returning does not implement [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) which is needed for `for...of` loops. `Symbol.iterator` is not needed for `forEach()` as that is a method available already on the returned object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `querySnapshot`, which is what is returned from the get method, is not an array or an iterable.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

`forEach` is a [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) from the querySnapshot object, which is why you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.
The first when simply means that your object has a `forEach` method.

The second one means that your object has a `[Symbol.iterator]` property which is a generator. This makes your object iterable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Answer (score 0):

As Alberto Rivera stated, the forEach is a QuerySnaphot method and it does the work for you. But you can loop from those documents yourself by using:

```
    const entries = await db.collection('entries').get();
    for (entry of entries.docs) {
        console.log(entry.id);
    }
```

Note that ".docs" comes with your querysnapshot and its is iterable